# Type of class based on template type

Tags: c++

Consider this case where:

```
#include<iostream>

template<class U>
class Table_Inside {
  U a;
};

template<class T>
class Table {
  Table_Inside<T> *tmp;
};

int main() {
  Table<int> obj;
}
```

Doing this will create a data member of type `int` for `Table_Inside` class/object. I am struggling to think that what would happen if I remove templates for `Table_Inside` class and create two separate classes like `Table_Inside_int` and `Table_inside_char`. Assuming that only two options can come for `U`. In this case, how should we deal so that `Table` class has pointer to corresponding class. E.g.

```
#include<iostream>
class Table_Inside_int {
  int a;
};

class Table_Inside_char {
  char c;
}

template<class T>
class Table {
  /*<what to write here to create corresponding class pointer>*/ *tmp;
}

int main() {
  Table<int> obj;
}
```

So, if I pass,

```
Table<int> obj
```

It should create an pointer(tmp) of type `Table_Inside_int` inside Table class.

AND if I pass,

```
Table<char> obj
```

It should create an pointer(tmp) of type `Table_Inside_char` inside `Table` class.

Is it even possible in c++ world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If specialization doesn't quite work and there's only a couple types, an alias can be made using [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) and [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same):

```
// assumes only char or int will be passed
template <class T>
using Table_Inside = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, char>, Table_Inside_char, Table_Inside_int>;
```

This can be used just as before like `Table_Inside<T>`.

Comment: uh, what more are you looking for? `Table_Inside<T>` is a type alias for either `Table_Inside_char` or `Table_Inside_int` depending on what `T` is. `conditional` and `is_same` are type traits provided by the standard library

Comment: @kmdredo, where should I write this statement? Outside/Inside 'Table' class? I clearly do not get the usage part of this.

Comment: it can be inside or outside, but it only defines the type `Table_Inside`, the `tmp` declaration must be separate. Here's a [sample](https://onlinegdb.com/H133MbZIE) that shows it working. Or I suppose you can do it like you're doing and declare the type directly and not alias it, that sample has both the c++14 (as I have above) and c++11 variants.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done through *specialization*:

```
// The "base" generic case
template<typename T>
class Table_Inside;

template<>
class Table_Inside<char>
{
    // Special implementation for characters
};

template<>
class Table_Inside<int>
{
    // Special implementation for integers
};

template<typename T>
class Table
{
    Table_Inside<T>* tmp;
};
```

If you need common functionality shared between the `char` and `int` classes, then you can use inheritance for that.

Comment: Yes. That could be easily done. I am not sure which world I was living in. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this with some trait. Define

```
// Primary template
template <class T>
struct Table_Trait;

// Specialization
template <>
struct Table_Trait<int> { using type = Table_Inside_int; };

template <>
struct Table_Trait<char> { using type = Table_Inside_char; };

template <class T>
using Table_Inside_t = typename Table_Trait<T>::type;
```

and use it via

```
template<class T>
class Table {
    Table_Inside_t *tmp;
};
```

However, there might be a simpler solution if there is no need to have independent classes `Table_Inside_int` and `Table_Inside_double`. You can use specialization also directly

```
// Primary template
template <class T>
class Table_Inside;

// Specialization
template <>
class Table_Inside<int> { /* implementation for int */ };

template <>
class Table_Inside<char> { /* implementation for char */ };
```